# Google game service and iOS game center score not showing in the leaderboared using corona sdk

Tags: android, ios, iphone, coronasdk

I have a game developed in corona sdk that makes a use of google game service and ios game center.
I am using this code to post the leaderboard but the scores doesn't show in the leaderboared.

```
localPlayerScore = { category= activeNetworksProviders[currentSystem][2], value=tonumber(10) }, 
listener = function() 
    local test = native.showAlert( "Score was posted", "Score was posted", {"ok"})
end
```

But the score is posted but it doesn't show in the leaderboard.
Here is a game try it out and u will see the scoreboared empty.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgames.flappingball

Where can the problem lies? Help

Comment: What debugging have you done to try to fix this error?  Have you looked at the logs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I think i have used the wrong leaaderboard number. What should i use for my leaderboard id the leaderboard id i have created in itunesconnect right? but it doesn't save the score online in my leaderboard.